# How to merge columns from different sheets without duplicates?

Tags: excel, merge, duplicates, vba

How can I merge two columns of data from two different sheets into one column on a third sheet without duplicates?

For Example:

Sheet 1

```
ID
1
2
3
```

and
Sheet 2

```
ID
1
6
7
3
```

become Sheet 3

```
1
2
3
6
7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do it by an extension of the usual formula for listing unique values which would be

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($a$1:a1, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4), 0))
```

for the first list

and

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($a$1:a1, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5), 0))
```

for the second list

In pseudo-code

```
If at end of first list
    If at end of second list
        Show nothing
    Else
        Show next item from second list 
Else
    If at end of second list
        Show next item from first list
    ELse
        Show smaller of (next item from first list, next item from second list)
```

So the combined formula would be

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4), 0))),
   IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5), 0))),
   "",
   INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5), 0))),
   IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5), 0))),
    INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4), 0)),
    MIN(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4), 0)),
     INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5), 0)))
 ))
```

starting in Sheet3!A2.

All of these are array formulae.

This version works for numbers only.

A version that works for numbers and text:-

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet1!  $A$2:$A$4),0))),
  IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet2!  $A$2:$A$5),0))),
  "",
  INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5),0))),
  IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5),0))),
  INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4),0)),
   IF( INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4),0))
   <INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5),0)),
    INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4),0)),
    INDEX  (Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5),0)))
 ))
```

x Doesn't sort

x Doesn't skip blanks

✓ Does preserve order if lists are already in ascending order.