# Merge values in multiple columns into one

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following data structure:
[image: Data+Expected Results+What I get]

As you see in **column J**, I am trying to merge data into one column from columns **A** & **C** & **E** & **G**.

I am using this formula:

```
=IF(ROW()<=COUNTA($A:$A);INDEX($A:$C;ROW();COLUMN(A1));INDEX($A:$C;ROW()-COUNTA($A:$A)+1;COLUMN(C1)))
```

and I get the values in column **K** as you see. Currently this formula is merging only two columns. **How to modify it to merge all four columns?**

And how to only get those values starting from **row 5**?

The column height will vary constantly: sometimes there are 10 values in column A and sometimes there are 2 values.

*Either any excel formula or any VBA code will be acceptable.*

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Is is getting the first non-empty result on on the line (columns a, c, e, and g)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a fairly standard method for retrieving unique values from a column but not multiple columns. To achieve the retrieval from multiple columns you need to stack multiple formulas together with the processing being passed to successive columns one the earlier formula errors out.

[image: Collect Unique from multiple columns]

The **array formula**¹ in J5 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$5:$A$99, MATCH(0, IF(LEN($A$5:$A$99), COUNTIF(J$4:J4, $A$5:$A$99), 1), 0)),
 IFERROR(INDEX($C$5:$C$99, MATCH(0, IF(LEN($C$5:$C$99), COUNTIF(J$4:J4, $C$5:$C$99), 1), 0)),
 IFERROR(INDEX($E$5:$E$99, MATCH(0, IF(LEN($E$5:$E$99), COUNTIF(J$4:J4, $E$5:$E$99), 1), 0)),
 IFERROR(INDEX($G$5:$G$99, MATCH(0, IF(LEN($G$5:$G$99), COUNTIF(J$4:J4, $G$5:$G$99), 1), 0)),
 ""))))
```

I have only included columns A, C, E and G as your sample data shows only duplicates in columns B, D, F, and H.

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: This answers the question perfectly. But if you had overlapping lists and wanted to preserve the order, you could merge pairs of columns using the method I outlined here and merge the result - a bit cumbersome I admit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995903/how-to-merge-columns-from-different-sheets-without-duplicates/30001917#30001917

Comment: This is a beautiful formula.  On your point about multi-column difficulties, I went ahead and added an answer that builds a single column first and then runs the usual formula across it.  You trade a helper column for a less nested formula.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is another way of thinking about the formulas you could use for this sort of task.  It gets to the point made by @Jeeped that it is difficult to find unique values in multiple columns.  My first step then is to create a single column.

If you can live with a helper column, these formulas might be a tad easier to maintain than the nested `IFERROR` already proposed.  They are equally difficult to understand though at first glance.  The other upside is that it scales nicely if the number of columns involved increases.

It is possible using `CHOOSE` and some `INDEX` math to build a single column array of a group of separated columns.  The trick is that `CHOOSE` will join discontinuous ranges side-by-side when given an array as the selecting parameter.  If this starts with columns of the same size, you can then use division and mod math to turn it into a single column.

**Picture of ranges** shows the four groups of data with duplicates colored red.

[image: picture of ranges]

**Formula** in `F2:F31` is an array formula.  This is combining all of the columns into an array and then back into a single column.  I selected the columns out of order just to emphasize that it is handling a discontinuous range.

```
=INDEX(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4}, A2:A7,C2:C7,B2:B7,D2:D7), MOD(ROW(1:30)-1, ROWS(A2:A7))+1,INT((ROW(1:30)-1)/ROWS(A2:A7))+1)
```

The array formula in `H2` and copied down is then the standard formula for unique values.  The one exception is that instead of avoiding blanks like normal, I am avoiding 0 values.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(F2:F31,MATCH(0,IF(F2:F31=0,1,COUNTIF($H$1:H1,F2:F31)),0)),"")
```

A couple  of other comments about this approach:

- In the `CHOOSE`, I am using `{1,2,3,4}`.  This could be replaced with `TRANSPOSE(ROWS(1:4))` or whatever number of columns you have.
- There is also a `ROWS(A2:A7)` in 2 places, this could just be `2:7` or `1:6` or whatever size was used for the column size.  I used one of the data ranges so that the coloring was simplified and to emphasize it needs to match the size of the block.
- And the `ROW(1:30)` is used for the number of total items to collect.  It really only needs to be `1:24` since there are `6*4` items, but I made it big while testing.

There are definitely a couple of downsides to this approach, but it may be a good trick to keep in the toolbox.  Never know when you might want to make a column out of discontinuous ranges.  The largest downside is that the columns of data all need to be the same size (and of course the helper column).

Comment: I tried this, but I can't even simulate your results. Is it because my delimiter is **;** and not ","  which affects the **choose** function? I replaced all of the commas with semicolons, however. But no success.

Comment: @Mpondomise, sorry did not even notice the different delimiter up above.  `CHOOSE` should take a _row_ array.  If you want to remove the delimiter there, just use `TRANPOSE(ROW(1:4))` instead of `{1,2,3,4}`, it will return the same array.  `ROW()` normally returns a column array and `TRANSPOSE` flips it around.

Comment: could you please modify your answer so that I can see what you mean? I may reproduce it with errors. Thanks

Comment: The formula would be: `=INDEX(CHOOSE(TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:4)), A2:A7,C2:C7,B2:B7,D2:D7), MOD(ROW(1:30)-1, ROWS(A2:A7))+1,INT((ROW(1:30)-1)/ROWS(A2:A7))+1)`.  I believe it is safe to flip all the commas to semicolons now.

Answer (score 1):

This code will do what you ask:

```
Sub MoveData()

START_ROW = 5
START_COL = 1
STEP_COL = 2
OUTPUT_ROW = 5
OUTPUT_COL = 10

Row = START_ROW
Col = START_COL
Out_Row = OUTPUT_ROW
While Col < OUTPUT_COL
    While Cells(Row, Col).Value <> ""
        Cells(Out_Row, OUTPUT_COL).Value = Cells(Row, Col).Value
        Out_Row = Out_Row + 1
        Row = Row + 1
    Wend
    Row = START_ROW
    Col = Col + STEP_COL
Wend
```

End Sub

Comment: Your formula is working great! But these is a small problem: it doesn't stops looking for values after it hits a non empty cell. That is: if there is a blank cell in one of the columns and after that blank cell, there are some data, it doesn't include those data that come after that blank cell. However Jeeped's answer does include any cell that has data in it. Could you please modify it and put your answer in the [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30338724/4835480) that I have created for this.

Answer (score -3):

Think you guys are making this complicated. Just pull the range of data into power query , select all the columns and unpivot them this will bring all the data into a single column