# Merge data from multiple columns into one column

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following:
[image]

I am using [@BigBobby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30330091/4835480) to achieve this:

```
Sub MoveData()
Range("H5:H99").ClearContents
START_ROW = 5
START_COL = 1
STEP_COL = 2
OUTPUT_ROW = 5
OUTPUT_COL = 8
Limit_Col = 9

Row = START_ROW
Col = START_COL
Out_Row = OUTPUT_ROW
While Col < Limit_Col
    While Cells(Row, Col).Value <> ""
        Cells(Out_Row, OUTPUT_COL).Value = Cells(Row, Col).Value
        Out_Row = Out_Row + 1
        Row = Row + 1
    Wend
    Row = START_ROW
    Col = Col + STEP_COL
Wend
End Sub
```

But as you see, I expect to get those values which appear after a blank cell in the columns. But this code fails to pull those cells highlighted in yellow.

*How to modify this code to pull all of the data which may appear after one or several blank cells?*

Comment: You're getting the error because your 2nd While loop moves down the column until it finds a blank, once it finds one it moves across 2 columns. I'd suggest you just need to add in a line which identifies the last row in the column which has data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust this code:

```
While Cells(Row, Col).Value <> ""
    Cells(Out_Row, OUTPUT_COL).Value = Cells(Row, Col).Value
    Out_Row = Out_Row + 1
    Row = Row + 1
Wend
```

For:

```
Do until row > Cells(65536, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(Out_Row, OUTPUT_COL).Value = Cells(Row, Col).Value
    Out_Row = Out_Row + 1
    Row = Row + 1
Loop
```

This essentially checks to see if the row has passed the last row with data, and if it has, it moves onto the next column.

**Edit**

To not copy across the blank cells use this:

```
    Do until row > Cells(65536, Col).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(Row, Col).Value <> "" then
            Cells(Out_Row, OUTPUT_COL).Value = Cells(Row, Col).Value
            Out_Row = Out_Row + 1
        End If
        Row = Row + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: this code runs faster that Bigbobby's answer, but it includes those blanks cells in the results as well. How to modify the code not to include those blank cells?

Comment: So it does! I've updated it to skip over the blank cells. I've not tested it but have a go and see if you can make it work if it doesn't already.

Comment: Although just seen Bigbobby's answer, I'm sure you can tinker with it to speed it up!

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is close, but it will also copy all of the blank spaces.  This code should do what you need:

```
Sub MoveData()

START_ROW = 5
START_COL = 1
STEP_COL = 2
OUTPUT_ROW = 5
OUTPUT_COL = 10

Row = START_ROW
Col = START_COL
Out_Row = OUTPUT_ROW
While Col < OUTPUT_COL
    While Row < ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Cells(Row, Col).Value <> "" Then
            Cells(Out_Row, OUTPUT_COL).Value = Cells(Row, Col).Value
            Out_Row = Out_Row + 1
        End If
        Row = Row + 1
    Wend
    Row = START_ROW
    Col = Col + STEP_COL
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: this is working. But it is taking so long to run the command. Why is that?

Comment: How much data do you have?  It runs quickly here, but I am not testing with many rows and I have a very fast computer.  One trick you can use to make macros go faster, is to include:    `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of the macro, and then `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end.  That way, Excel isn't repainting the screen after every operation that affects a cell.